# Render part to another top level zone using placement file - Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I want to move the Title and Body parts into the the AsideFirst top level zone using the placement file. I am using the following syntax in my placement file:

```
<Match ContentType="Event">
    <Place Parts_Title="/AsideFirst:1;"/>
    <Place Parts_Common_Body="/AsideFirst:2;"/>
</Match>
```

This is not working. The Event's Title and Body part are disappearing completely.

I have defined my AsideFirst zone in the theme.txt file, and the Layout.cshtml file is as follows:

```
@Zone(Model.AsideFirst)
```

Please note I have a "/" in my Place value as this is the syntax for rendering parts to top level zones. I have also tried this on a completely different content item, part and zone which did not work either.

The reason why I am doing through the placement file is that I want to eventually match a specific URL path so this only happens on a particular page.

I am using Orchard 1.7.1.

Comment: Please remove the semicolon from the zonename. I think it should be:
`<Match ContentType="Event">
    <Place Parts_Title="/AsideFirst:1"/>
    <Place Parts_Common_Body="/AsideFirst:2"/>
</Match>`

Comment: That solved the issue, thanks mate. You should submit your comment as an actual answer so I can accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the semicolon from the zonename. I think it should be:

```
<Match ContentType="Event"> 
    <Place Parts_Title="/AsideFirst:1"/>
    <Place Parts_Common_Body="/AsideFirst:2"/> 
</Match>
```